# pythonw.exe is not responding

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been learning Python2.7 for a little bit now. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit BTW. I started learning GUI's and have been trying to use wxpython and IDLE for this. So I type out some code:

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
win = wx.Frame(None)
win.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I run the program, and the window pops up, but the blue doughnut is there. I try to close the window, and it says that pythonw.exe is not responding. Another window pops up about wxpython. It says:

```
wxPython stdout/stderr(Not Responding)

Traceback (most recent call last):
**IDLE Internal Exception:
File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 93, in main
seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 177, in get
self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 263, in wait
_sleep(delay)
typeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is most likely happening at the point when you try and start the event loop. See this bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue989712

Seems someone else has gone as far to try and create an extension to handle this ability: http://idlex.sourceforge.net/extensions.html

Basically, don't do this from IDLE. Write a script and run it from the shell or the script directly if in windows, by naming it with a .pyw extension and double clicking it. There is apparently a conflict between IDLE's own event loop and the ones from GUI toolkits.

Comment: The EventLoop.py extension from IdleX allows the wx toolkit to run without calling app.Mainloop().

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something might be polluting variables in the `threading` library, it looks like `_sleep` variable is being overwritten with an `int` value; in which case `_sleep(x)` will not work since `_sleep` is an `int` and `int`s are not callable.

It may be in your client code or in some framework code or libraries you are `import`ing. Is that all of the code?

Try running this code from a plain python terminal, not from an IDE like IDLE.