# Compiling WxPython with Py2EXE and IDLE-X

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

At the moment i am learning python and i have been experimenting compiling python code.

The problem i am having is, once the script is compiled, it does not respond.

I learnt that an IDLE-X extension can help fix this problem, but the same error occurs after compilation. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bit, wxPython 2.7, python 2.7 and py2exe for 2.7. ->

```
import wx

class aero(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Aero v1.0b', size=(500,500))
    panel=wx.Panel(self)

    status=self.CreateStatusBar()
    menubar=wx.MenuBar()
    first=wx.Menu()
    second=wx.Menu()
    first.Append(wx.NewId(),"New Window","This is a new window" )
    first.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...","This will open a new window" )
    menubar.Append(first,"File")
    menubar.Append(second,"Edit")
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)


if __name__=='__main__':
app=wx.PySimpleApp()
frame=aero(parent=None,id=-1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop
```

i  got some help off this thread: [pythonw.exe is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987419/pythonw-exe-is-not-responding)

and i would like to learn why this happens.

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since py2exe isn't getting updated much any more, I would recommend trying PyInstaller or cx_freeze instead.