# The window popup of image shown through cv2.imshow() is closing very fast for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, imshow

Just a sample code

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('book.jpg')
cv.imshow('img', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

As soon as the window opens, it closes, I am not able to even see the images properly.

I thought it was happening because I was using WSL (Linux) but the same thing is happening for me in windows too.

The same thing works fine on my friends computer. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct, and `img` holds data?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes, because for a slight second it does show up and I can see the image, but the screen is not persisting for some weird reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50091712

Answer (score 0):

So a workaround for this is to add destroyAllWindows task to the queue and delay it.

the new code would be then

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('book.jpg')
cv.imshow('img', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
cv.waitKey(1)
```

thanks to @AbhinavMathur comment

Comment: "queue"? there is no queue. what are you talking about? -- `waitKey(0)`, as in the question's code, should have made the window responsive and available until some button is pressed or the window is explicitly closed.