# Opencv Not displaying image inside docker

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, docker

I am trying to use the OpenCV imshow GUI from inside the docker container. 
I used the following to start the container I using nvidia-docker because, the container contains GPU version of Tensorflow

```
xhost +
nvidia-docker run \
--rm \
--name tf_keras \
--link mongodb_database:data_mongo \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-v $1:/abhijit_home \
-p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 \
tensorflow_gpu_v1
```

When I try to display am image using OpenCV I am just getting a blank screen. 
[image]

The Image I am trying to display is displayed using matplotlib. How can I correct this? Thanks

Comment: Jupyter notebooks have known issues displaying images with `cv2.imshow()`. The short of it is, don't use it inside a Jupyter notebook. Use another plotting library to show the image in-line. Alternatively, you can save the image and then display it inline with HTML or other Jupyter notebook features. However, there is possible workarounds using `cv2.startWindowThread()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584090/5087436).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having the same issue with OpenCV and Docker.

Comment: Do you found any solution on this? I need to display a lot of image in line and cannot save it because performance

Answer (score -2):

This is probably related to `matplotlib`.  Try

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: It is not, as OpenCV does not use `matplotlib`.