# Code with open cv in python in macos: process is launched in terminal but nothing happens

Tags: python, macos, opencv, terminal

I am trying to display an image using open cv and used the following code (from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-namedwindow-function/)). However, when I run from the terminal (with zsh in MacOS 11.6.1 using `Python 3.7.5` and `opencv-python==4.2.0.34` a python process is launched and nothing more happens (there is no error message and no image is appearing). What am I doing wrong?

```
import cv2
 
# Path to image in local directory
path = 'path/to/image.png'
 
# Using cv2.imread() to read an image in grayscale mode
image = cv2.imread(path, 0)
 
# Using namedWindow()
# A window with 'Display_Image' name is created
# with WINDOW_NORMAL allowing us to have random size
cv2.namedWindow("Display_Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
 
# Using cv2.imshow() to display the image
cv2.imshow('Display_Image', image)
 
# Waiting 0ms for user to press any key
cv2.waitKey(0)
 
# Using cv2.destroyAllWindows() to destroy
# all created windows open on screen
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Edit**

I edited the code according to comment to print the size of the image as follows with the following output in the terminal : `(480, 640)`. But still no image nor error message happens

```
import cv2
 
# Path to image in local directory
path = 'path/to/image.png'
 
# Using cv2.imread() to read an image in grayscale mode
image = cv2.imread(path, 0)
print(image.shape) 

 
# Using namedWindow()
# A window with 'Display_Image' name is created
# with WINDOW_NORMAL allowing us to have random size
cv2.namedWindow("Display_Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
 
# Using cv2.imshow() to display the image
cv2.imshow('Display_Image', image)
 
# Waiting 0ms for user to press any key
cv2.waitKey(0)
 
# Using cv2.destroyAllWindows() to destroy
# all created windows open on screen
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is there any error message printed out in the terminal? For example cv2.imread might return None if the image path is wrong which might break the code later on ..

As starter you may want to check what the read image is not None and print out its shape. Next you can also try plotting the image using matplotlib, just to see whether its opencv drawing issue or something else.

plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray'); plt.show()

Comment: @GpG. Thank you for your comment: there is no error message and I could print the size of the image. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: macos always causes these issues. it's hobbling you with permission issues at every step. see if any of that is the cause. see if you can open a matplotlib window, or a tkinter window.

Comment: How do you run, or debug you code ?

Comment: @alibustami I just run this exact same script from the terminal in a dedicated python environment with installed packages (`cv2` and `matplotlib` among others)

Comment: Have you tried running from a code editor?

Comment: @alibustami Code editor you mean something such a platform such as VS Code where you can both write and run the code? I use `vim` as text editor and run the script in the terminal. As far as I know if it does not work from the terminal, it will no work better in something like VS code which just an additional layer that eventualy does the same as the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after following the github thread there https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/423, I updated the package to the newest version (in my case `opencv-python-4.6.0.66`) and it worked.